# Can I add a picture while sharing a post from a different website on twitter?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter

Javascript:

```
window.open('http://www.twitter.com/share?text=xxxxxxxx');
```

For facebook we can use

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.somedomain.ext/skin/images/my-img.jpg" />
```

order to add a picture with the content of the post.
So I'm wondering if I could do something similar for twitter.

Comment: Have you tried using Twitter Cards? https://dev.twitter.com/cards

Comment: I've looked into that, but it doesn't seems to be useful to me or I can't understand how to use it. My question was, if a user can share some twitt like you can do with FB share button, including a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Twitter specific meta-data to your post, as described on the [Twitter cards site](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo).

For examples (replace images & names with your own values):

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mountain sunset" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7334/11858349453_e3f18e5881_z.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.flickr.com/photos/reza-sina/11858349453/" />
```

You will also need to run your site through the [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator).

Comment: My question was to allow the people click on a Twitter share button and twit a text with image